# Getting Bad File descriptor Error in python after catching recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, operating-system, daemon

I am trying to learn more about dameonizing process in python. I ran the below code and got two errors

1. [2020-03-19 08:43:06,079 40116 MainProcess test.py file_read 35: ERROR] maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
2. [2020-03-19 08:43:08,766 40116 MainProcess test.py file_read 35: ERROR] [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor [while trying to close foo]

While 1 makes sense but 2nd does not. Can somebody help me out here?

```
def file_read(filename):
    file_content = None
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        try:
            logging.finfo('loading file %s' % filename)
            file_content = read_meta_file(file)

        except (FileNotFoundError, ApacheConfigError) as err:
            logging.exception(err)

        with daemon.DaemonContext():
            pass

        try:
            file_read(filename)
        except Exception as err:
            logging.ferror(err)
            raise


    return file_content


file_read('foo.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using recursion i.e function calling itself, you must have a breaking condition that will eventually end the recursion. In your code, there isn't any breaking condition.